# System.TypeLoadException for DropShadow

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

Trying out the `HeaderedTextBlock` control in the `UWP-Community-toolkit`, I get
`'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.dll`
`Additional information: Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.UI.Composition.DropShadow'.`

**StackTrace**

```
   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_UI_Controls_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.InitTypeTables()
   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_UI_Controls_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.LookupTypeIndexByName(String typeName)
   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_UI_Controls_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.GetXamlTypeByName(String typeName)
   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_UI_Controls_XamlTypeInfo.XamlMetaDataProvider.GetXamlType(String fullName)
   at Test_uwp.Test_uwp_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.CheckOtherMetadataProvidersForName(String typeName)
   at Test_uwp.Test_uwp_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.GetXamlTypeByName(String typeName)
   at Test_uwp.App.GetXamlType(String fullName)
```

Where
`typeName`: `Windows.UI.Composition.DropShadow` and
`fullName`: `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.HamburgerMenu`

*Where is `HamburgerMenu` even coming from?*

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Class="Test_uwp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test_uwp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <controls:HeaderedTextBlock 
            Header="Name"
            Text="UWP Toolkit"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Margin="20,10,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Test_uwp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the same exception with `RadialGuage`.
Toolkit version: `1.2.0`

Answer (score 2):

I followed the [getting Started with the UWP Toolkit page](http://uwpcommunitytoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/Getting-Started/) to setup uwp community toolkit. It worked well in my side.

Please check if your environment achieve the requirement:

1. Ensure you choose the custom install option and select the Universal Windows App Development Tools
2. Build 10586 or higher is supported by current version of the Toolkit.

You could also run the [source code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) in your side, if the environment has no problems, it should work.

If you have any other concern regarding this issue, please feel free to let me know.